# (ES6) Search filter with <option> selected Attributes

Tags: javascript, json, forms, filter, ecmascript-6

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "clubs":  [
    {
    "name": "Feyenoord Rotterdam",
    "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
    "championships": "15 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu743"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sparta Rotterdam",
      "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
      "championships": "6 Titles",
      "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu744"
    },
    {
      "name": "AZ Alkmaar",
      "origin": "Noord-Holland",
      "championships": "2 Titles",
      "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu745"
    },
    {
      "name": "Willem II",
      "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
      "championships": "3 Titles",
      "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu746"
    },
    {
      "name": "PSV Eindhoven",
      "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
      "championships": "24 Titles",
      "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu747"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make a form so that you can filter the clubs on origin. I have this html code:

```
<form class="search-origin">
  <select name="Search club from origin">
    <option value="zuid-holland">Zuid-Holland</option>
    <option value="noord-holland">Noord-Brabant</option>
    <option value="noord-brabant">Noord-Holland</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

So if you select "Zuid-Holland" only the clubs "Feyenoord Rotterdam" and "Sparta Rotterdam" are visible.

I can make it work with buttons, but I really want to make it work with a form and ES6.

Comment: What is the question? Do you have issues with getting `Array.filter()` to work? Or getting the value from the select?

Comment: Getting the value from the select. I don't really know where to start.

Comment: You select the element from the DOM, probably with document.querySelector(). The you just get the value property of that select, so you have the string of the correct province. Then you can array.filter() the clubs array in your data so you get an array with only the clubs of that province. Finally just feed that array back into whatever function you use to render the full list of clubs when there is no filter selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `Array#filter()` like so:

```js
let data = {"clubs":[{"name":"Feyenoord Rotterdam","origin":"Zuid-Holland","championships":"15 Titles","image":"https://goso.gl/images/Dgu743"},{"name":"Sparta Rotterdam","origin":"Zuid-Holland","championships":"6 Titles","image":"https://goso.gl/images/Dgu744"},{"name":"AZ Alkmaar","origin":"Noord-Holland","championships":"2 Titles","image":"https://goso.gl/images/Dgu745"},{"name":"Willem II","origin":"Noord-Brabant","championships":"3 Titles","image":"https://goso.gl/images/Dgu746"},{"name":"PSV Eindhoven","origin":"Noord-Brabant","championships":"24 Titles","image":"https://goso.gl/images/Dgu747"}]};

document.querySelector(".search-origin").addEventListener("change", e => {
  let val = e.target.value; //get the value from the form
  console.log(val);
  let searched = data.clubs.filter(d => d.origin.toLowerCase() === val);
  display(searched);
});

function display(data) {
  /** Display the data somehow **/
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<form class="search-origin">
<select name="Search club from origin">
<option value="zuid-holland">Zuid-Holland</option>
<option value="noord-holland">Noord-Holland</option>
<option value="noord-brabant">Noord-Brabant</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: This works out well! Is it possible to not use the let data? So that I use the separate JSON file?

Comment: Sure, just replace that with however you get the data. If you have problems later on you can always ask a new question!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const clubs = [{
    "name": "Feyenoord Rotterdam",
    "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
    "championships": "15 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu743"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sparta Rotterdam",
    "origin": "Zuid-Holland",
    "championships": "6 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu744"
  },
  {
    "name": "AZ Alkmaar",
    "origin": "Noord-Holland",
    "championships": "2 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu745"
  },
  {
    "name": "Willem II",
    "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
    "championships": "3 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu746"
  },
  {
    "name": "PSV Eindhoven",
    "origin": "Noord-Brabant",
    "championships": "24 Titles",
    "image": "https://goso.gl/images/Dgu747"
  }
];

function filter(event) {
 const e = document.getElementById('clubs-select');
 const region = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 const d = document.getElementById('possible-clubs');
 d.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(clubs.filter(function(club) {
  return club.origin.toLowerCase() === region;
 }));
}
```

```html
<form class="search-origin">
  <select name="Search club from origin" id="clubs-select" onChange="filter();">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="zuid-holland">Zuid-Holland</option>
    <option value="noord-holland">Noord-Brabant</option>
    <option value="noord-brabant">Noord-Holland</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="possible-clubs"></div>
```